# How to use reflection to get generic lists of a particular type

Tags: c#, reflection

How do I use .NET reflection to get a list of properties that are of a particular class, including generic lists, e.g. I have a class that looks like this:

```
class Test
{
    [NotConditional()]
    [Order( 1 )]
    public Value Name { get; set; }

    [NotConditional()]
    [Order( 2 )]
    public Value Address { get; set; }

    [NotConditional()]
    [Order( 3 )]
    public List<Value> Contacts { get; set; }
}
```

I want to get the `Name`, `Address` and `Contacts` properties as all of them are of type `Value`.

I have the following code, which works great, but I want the `List<>` bit to only pick up `List<Value>` properties.

```
var props = from p in this.GetType().GetProperties()
            where p.PropertyType.IsSubclassOf( typeof( Std ) ) ||
            ( p.PropertyType.IsGenericType &&
              p.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof( List<> ) )
              select new { Property = p };
```

I have tried:

```
var props = from p in this.GetType().GetProperties()
            where p.PropertyType.IsSubclassOf( typeof( Std ) ) ||
            ( p.PropertyType.IsGenericType &&
              p.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof( List<Value> ) )
              select new { Property = p };
```

But, it doesn't pick up any `List<Value>` properties and only picks up `Name` and `Address` properties.

** UPDATE **

I have included these two classes as well as I also want to include properties that also derive from `Std`'.

```
class Std
{
    public int id { get; set; }
}

class Value : Std
{
    public string Val { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using GetGenericTypeDefinition when you don't actually *want* the generic type definition?

Comment: @JonSkeet That's because I found this code on a Stack Overflow post and used it as it's what I was looking for only that it did'nt pick up the `List<Value>` properties I also wanted.

Comment: In future, it's worth making sure that you *thoroughly* understand code from elsewhere before using it. I suspect you were looking at code which was trying to find properties of *any* list type, hence the call to `GetGenericTypeDefinition`.

Comment: @JonSkeet That's an excellent lesson to learn.  I did understand what the code was doing, but misinterpreted the reasoning of the `GetGenericTypeDefinition` method call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems pretty straightforward. Try this:

```
var props = from p in this.GetType().GetProperties()
            where p.PropertyType == typeof(Value) ||
                  p.PropertyType == typeof(List<Value>)
            select new { Property = p };
```

Or to handle subclasses of `Value` or `List<Value>`

```
var props = from p in this.GetType().GetProperties()
            where typeof(Value).IsAssignableFrom( p.PropertyType ) ||
                  typeof(List<Value>).IsAssignableFrom( p.PropertyType )
            select new { Property = p };
```

---

Given your update, if you want to get any property whose type is assignable from `Std` or is a list whose parameter is assignable from `Std`, that's a bit more difficult because `List<T>` is [invariant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx) with respect to `T`. If that's what you want, you can do something like this:

```
var props = from p in this.GetType().GetProperties()
            where typeof(Std).IsAssignableFrom( p.PropertyType ) ||
                  ( p.PropertyType.IsGenericType &&
                    p.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>) && 
                    typeof(Std).IsAssignableFrom( p.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0] ) )
            select new { Property = p };
```

<sup>Note that this version doesn't return properties whose types inherit from `List<Std>`.</sup>

Comment: I am aware of this.  A `List<Value>` is never going to be assigned to a `List<Std>` but I have other properties that derive from `Std` and would like them picked up as well as `Value` classes.

Comment: @Mike See my updated answer for an alternative solution that might work in your situation.